# Group by date and use column values as new column names while aggregating on metrics

Tags: pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have a dataframe at data and some other levels as shown below:

```
data_dict = {
              "Date":['2023-01-02','2023-02-02','2023-01-02','2023-02-02','2023-01-02','2023-02-02','2023-01-02','2023-02-02','2023-01-02'],
              "Funnel": ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'],
              "Metric_A": [23,0,0,0,1,0,45,18,0],
              "Metric_B": [0,0,0,0,12,9,0,8,6]

}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
```

I am looking to aggregate data at date level so that the output is like below:

Date Funnel_A_Metric_A Funnel_B_Metric_A Funnel_C_Metric_A Funnel_A_Metric_B Funnel_B_Metric_B Funnel_C_Metric_B

2023-01-02 68 1 0 0 12 1

So basically I want to group at date and get the sum of the values in columns metric a & b and create new columns for those values as <funnel_name_metric_) and the values will be the sum of the values across all relevent grouped rows.

Can someone please help me with this in Python?

Comment: Use `out = df.pivot_table(index='Date',columns='Funnel', aggfunc='sum')
out.columns = [f'Funnel_{b}_{a}' for a, b in out.columns]`